# Syntax understanding in Symfony cookbook

Tags: php, symfony

Could someone explain me the following line which is in the [Symfony Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data) (FYI the main topic is dynamic generation for Submitted Forms)

I don't undersand the following: **?** , neither the **array() :**

```
$sport = $event->getData()->getSport(); // getdata submited by the user in the Sport input
$positions = null === $sport ? array() : $sport->getAvailablePositions();

// is it similaire to that line? what the difference?
$positions = $event->getData()->getSport()->getAvailablePositions();
```

Comment: This does have nothing to do  with symfony, it's the shortest form of _if_ statement called ternary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

? is a **ternary if**; which is an if statement on a single line.
It could be rewritten as

```
if (null === $sport) {
    $positions = array(); // an empty array
} else {
    $positions = $sport->getAvailablePositions();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line says, if `$sport` is null (=== means check both type/value), `$sport` will be an empty `array()`, if not, `$sport` will be `$sport->getAvailablePositions();`

`$positions` just get the result of it!

Answer (score 0):

It's a ternary condition operator. It's the factorisation of an if then followed by an affectation.[Documentation](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

Answer (score 0):

This is called "Ternary Logic". You can check for a good article on this here: http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

The logic is:

1. Is $sport null?
2. If so, return an array
3. Otherwise, get the availablePosition collection

The goal is to have something iterable at the end and in all cases, like an array, a collection, etc.

It is not similar to `$positions = $event->getData()->getSport()->getAvailablePositions();` because this will throw an error if `getSport()` returns null, thus calling `getAvailablePosition()` on something null.